# Drupal 7: hook for comments placeholder

Tags: hooks, comments

How can i implement a hook in my theme template that will display a placeholder in my comment box? I am using drupal 7 and zen sub theme. Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://www.digett.com/blog/05/26/2011/how-theme-comment-form-drupal-7) to modify your comment form.

Also have a look at [How Theme Comment Form Drupal 7](http://www.digett.com/blog/05/26/2011/how-theme-comment-form-drupal-7) wich will tell you exactly how to achive this.